How to turn specific docx table into markdown?
I have a specific docx table and i want to turn it into markdown using python
Hi. I have a docx file with this table:

i want to turn it into markdown using python. i tried this:
from docx import Document
from tabulate import tabulate

def extract_table_from_docx(docx_path):
    doc = Document(docx_path)
    table_data = []

    # Assuming the first table in the document
    table = doc.tables[0]

    for row in table.rows:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.cells:
            # Replace newline characters with a space or any delimiter to keep the cell content together
            cell_text = ' '.join(cell.text.strip().split('\n'))
            row_data.append(cell_text)
        table_data.append(row_data)

    return table_data

def convert_table_to_markdown(table_data):
    # Use the first row as headers
    headers = table_data[0]
    rows = table_data[1:]
    return tabulate(rows, headers=headers, tablefmt="github")


# Extract table data from DOCX file
path = "file.docx"
table_data = extract_table_from_docx(path)

# Convert table data to Markdown
markdown_table = convert_table_to_markdown(table_data)

# Print the Markdown table
print(markdown_table)


but i get this:
| p/p   | Category/Technical     | Subcategory       | Equipment, materials              | Type of equipment, destination                 | Priority manufacturer                       |    |
|-------|------------------------|-------------------|-----------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|----|
| p/p   | policy                 | Subcategory       | Equipment, materials              | application                                    | Priority manufacturer                       |    |
|       | policy                 |                   |                                   | application                                    |                                             |    |
| 1     | 2                      | 3                 | 4                                 | 5                                              | 6                                           |    |
|       |                        |                   | Transformers (low voltage)        | OSM type transformers                          | Tula transformer plant                      |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | Off.Av., Triggers, UZO, UZIP                   | Сhint, Hyundai, КЭАЗ                        |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | Contacts                                       | Electrical technician, KEAZ                 |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | Circuit breakers for direct current (including | KEAZ, Hint, Akel                            |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | to the current station for RZ)                 | KEAZ, Hint, Akel                            |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | to the current station for RZ)                 |                                             |    |
|       |                        | Low voltage (not  |                                   | Low voltage switches of type                   | DKC, КЭАЗ, IEK                              |    |
|       |                        | Low voltage (not  | Other equipment (not available    | ПКУ, УП                                        | DKC, КЭАЗ, IEK                              |    |
|       |                        | Low voltage (not  | Other equipment (not available    | ПКУ, УП                                        |                                             |    |
|       |                        | explosion proof)  | Other equipment (not available    | ПКУ, УП                                        |                                             |    |
|       |                        | explosion proof)  | Other equipment (not available    | Drawers type YA5000 NKU drawers                |                                             |    |
|       |                        | explosion proof)  | explosion proof)                  | Drawers type YA5000 NKU drawers                | Promeltech, IEK                             |    |
|       |                        |                   | explosion proof)                  | Drawers type YA5000 NKU drawers                | Promeltech, IEK                             |    |
|       |                        |                   | explosion proof)                  | electric control                               | Promeltech, IEK                             |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | electric control                               |                                             |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | Control cabinets and alarm cabinets,           |                                             |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | control stations, boxes                        | Center "Promservice" on the construct DKC   |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | connecting and splitting (Not                  | Center "Promservice" on the construct DKC   |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | connecting and splitting (Not                  |                                             |    |
|       |                        |                   |                                   | explosion-proof)                               |                                             |    |
......

as you see column name "Category/Technical policy" is being splitted into several rows, which is wrong. How to solve this issue?

Hi, did you end up figuring out a solution to this problem?
